# Life on Mars__?

Tags: shoftim--book-of, outer-space

in [Shoftim 5:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.23?lang=bi),

> 'Curse ye Meroz', said the angel of the LORD, 'Curse ye bitterly the inhabitants thereof, because they came not to the help of the LORD, to the help of the LORD against the mighty.'

Meroz is identified in the Talmud (Moed Kattan 16a) as (according to one opinion) a star or celestial body,

> ...מרוז איכא דאמרי גברא רבה הוה ואיכא דאמרי כוכבא הוה...

I'm curious to know whether anyone says that Meroz is another name for Mars - I know that it isn't the usual Hebrew name, but there are often multiple names for things and it does sound quite similar to Mars.

Comment: I would say it's implausible that a Latin name would be used in Tanach. 
That said apparently the Arabic word for the planet is (al)Mirichu (meaning something like fiery one) so not far off Meroz

Comment: @AKA but maybe this is where the Latin name come from?

Comment: Unlikely - the Latin name is from the Roman war god after whom they named the planet (following the Greeks and Babylonians in doing so)

Comment: @AKA all of which I think came after Devorah and Barak, so maybe the historians have it the wrong way around?  I think those cultures pretty much equated their deities with the planets so I don't think it is inconceivable

Comment: Feels unlikely, but not impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mikhel Weber](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8) wrote (Haye ha-'Olam ha-Bah, p. 106):

> על הכתוב (שופטים ה') "אורו מרוז אמר מלאך ה' אורו ארור יושביה" נאמר
> בתלמוד "איכא דאמרי כוכב הוה שנאמר ,מן השמים נלחמו הכוכבים" **ויש מפרשים
> את השם מרוז שהוא מארס (מאדים) וגם אמנם יש להם על מה לסמוך**

He states that there are some commentators that explain the name Meroz to mean Mars and they have wat to rely on. I'm not sure if he intends by "יש מפרשים" ("there are commentators") any traditionalists, as he was equally at home and conversant with both.

The encyclopedia Osar Yisrael (vol. 5, p. 265) on the entry for כוכבים ומזלות (stars and astrological constellations) quotes the Gemara as well and parenthetically makes the suggestion as well:

> איכא דאמרי כוכבא (מרוז Mars?)

[Abraham Krochmal](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9521-krochmal-abraham) in his critical glosses on the Talmud wrote (פירושים והארות לתלמוד בבלי על דרך העיון והבקורת p. 148):

> ומנלן דמשמתינן דכתיב אורו מרוז וכו ואמר עולא בארבע מאה שיפורי שמתיה
> ברק למרוז איכא דאמרי גברא רבה הוה ואיכא דאמרי כוכבא הוה ע"כ ומפרש
> בקונטרס כוכבא הוה מזליה דסיסרא עכ"ל ולי נראה כי הכוונה על Mars אליל
> המלחמות ושרי הצבאות והוא כוכב מאדים בכוכבי לכת.

A. Krochmal here states that it seems to him that the intent is to refer to Mars.

R. Shelomo Sadoq writes (Midrash Shelomo Ha-Meor Le-Aggadah p. 288):

> למ"ד כוכבא הוה **ניתן לומד שהכוונה על מאדים (הנקרא בלעז מארס)** שלפי
> אמונות הקדמונים הנו אליל מלחמה (ועי' כתר מלכות לאבן גבירול שסובר שהוא
> מקור למדה זו) והיו יוצאים למלחמה ע"פ הקוסמים והאיצטגנינים הוברי שמים
> החוזים להם בכוכבים הצלחות ונצחונות ודבורה בשירתה תיארה תוך התול ולעג
> במרוז שלפי ההוזים הוא השיא לסיסרא ובישר על נצחונו והצלחתו במלחמה
> ובהתאם לשטותם ואמנותם אררה דבורה למרוו אלילם ואמרה מדוע משמש הוא למדיח
> להם ואינו כשאר כוכבים שלא מיחסים להם כח מלחמה אלא לש"י בלבד אשר לו
> המלחמה והתשועה

R. Sadoq proposes the identification with Mars as well.

So it seems that this view came into circulation in the late 19th/early 20th c. among non-traditional scholars and is contemporaneously upheld by at least one traditionally oriented source.